# Toggle Animate Div on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to Toggle animate the Margin of a div on button click but doesn't seem to work. Here is the code and the fiddle link. I found the solution in one of the previous posts but still couldn't get it right.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    if ($('.demo').css('margin-top') == '0') {
        $('.demo').animate({
            marginTop: '-160px'
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $('.demo').animate({
            marginTop: '0'
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vineetgnair/vmwratpf/)**

Thanks for help

Comment: Change `'0'` to `'0px'`.

Comment: @Vineet G Nair I think you got many solutions which are working. So please tick the answer which is working for you.. Thanks.

Comment: Done Yunus....new to Stack.. not quite aware of all the things.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

here `Margin-top` returns value in `px` so

Make your decision like bellow

```
 if ($('.demo').css('margin-top') == '0px') {...}
```

instead of

```
  if ($('.demo').css('margin-top') == '0') {..}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vmwratpf/2/)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to compare `margin-top` with `0px` instead of `0` only, see below code :

```
$('button').click(function () {
    if ($('.demo').css('margin-top') == '0px') {
        $('.demo').animate({
            marginTop: '-160px'
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $('.demo').animate({
            marginTop: '0'
        }, 1000);
    }

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmwratpf/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Please update the first condition with:

```
if ($('.demo').css('margin-top') == '0px') {
```

**[Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/vmwratpf/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

It's better to check the state of your element with a class instead of `margin-top`. For example when the user click multiple times immediately on the `button`, your code will behave strangely. Try something like this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    if (! $('.demo').hasClass('done')) {
        $('.demo').addClass('done');
        $('.demo').stop().animate({
            marginTop: '-160px'
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        $('.demo').removeClass('done');
        $('.demo').stop().animate({
            marginTop: '0'
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vmwratpf/9/).

Comment: you said that when the user clicks multiple times immediately then the code will behave strangely. Didi you try to click on the button multiples times in your fiddle ?? If not please try that and see.

Comment: @Yunus Yes, I tried. When the user click, it will slideup, and when the user click again, the slideup will stop and menu will slidedown (the user break the previous action) and so on.